# How do you build an apk with javafxports android and ant?

Tags: java, android, javafx, ant, javafxports

I have tryed to build the apk with the project generated but I keep getting errors. I have been using ant clean debug to create but I keep getting errors with it not being able to find the build-extras.xml I have check and the build extras are at the path:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\android-tools\build-extras.xml
```

So how do you build an apk with javafxports android and ant?

Here is my cmd log if it helps:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\android\Ensemble8Android>ant clean debug
Buildfile: C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\android\Ensemble8Android\build.xml
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\android\Ensemble8Android\build.xml:69: Cannot find    C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\android-tools\build-extras.xml imported from C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalviksdk\samples\Ensemble8\android\Ensemble8Android\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
```

ant.properties:

```
jfx.sdk.absolute.dir=C\:/Users/svond_000/Documents/dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3
jfx.app.absolute.dist.dir=../../ensemble
isDalvik=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking for the Android sdk in:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\
```

But you have it located in:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\
```

**Just correct it in the `local.properties` file or the `ant.properties` file.**

Answer (score 2):

you probably have wrong path in file build.xml in line 69 to your build-extras.xml - there is no "-" sign

you have there path:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk8u40-ea3\...
```

and should have:

```
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\...
```

Comment: Sorry it still shows the same error but thanks for trying. There might be more than one thing wrong with the path or it might be a different error

Comment: It apears to be the same as the first just with the dash(-) where you said to put it BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\an
droid\Ensemble8Android\build.xml:69: Cannot find C:\Users\svond_000\Documents\da
lvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\android-tools\build-extras.xml imported from C:\Users\svond_00
0\Documents\dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3\dalvik-sdk\samples\Ensemble8\antroid\Ensemble8An
droid\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: did you create build.xml file by yourself or was it generated? could you post project.properties or ant.properties

Comment: It was generated and I added the ant.properties to the question.